# Batch File to move avi up a directory

Tags: batch-file

I need to move lots of .avi files out of folders up one directory and each folder has a unique name, I've googled lots of scripts and not found any working way to do this. If anyone could give me some help that would be great.

eg:

- Main_Directory

  - Sub_Directory_1

    - file_1.avi
  - Sub_Directory_2

    - file_2.avi
  - [etc]...

I want to move all the .avi's in the Sub-directorys into the Main-directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
for /d %%f in ("c:\directory\*") do (
    if exist "%%~ff\*.avi" echo move "%%~ff\*.avi" "%%~dpf"
)
```

List of move commands is echoed to console. If it is correct, remove the `echo` command

EDITED - Code included was written for batch file usage and confortable screen read. For command line usage, it is necessary to replace the double percent signs with single percent signs, and is easier to write it in a single line.

```
for /d %f in ("c:\directory\*") do @if exist "%~ff\*.avi" @echo move "%~ff\*.avi" "%~dpf"
```

The included `@` signs (not necessary) are to hide the command execution. That way, the only output to console is the echo command. And as in the previous code, if output is correct, run it again without the `echo` command to execute the move operation

Comment: My guess is they are doing it from the command line. 20:1 odds. any takers? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set root=C:\PathtoMain\Main\
pushd "%root%"

for /r %%a in (*.avi) do (
move "%%~a" "%root%"
)

popd
```

And that should solve your problem.

Mona.